# Find the derivative of $\cos^4 (x) \sin^4(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find the derivative of $\cos^4 (x) \sin^4(x)$

---

The professor gave me the answer $\frac12 \sin^3 (2x) \cos(2x)$, but different online derivative calculators give me a different answer

$$ 4 \cos^3 (x) \sin^3 (x) \left( \cos^2 (x) - \sin^2 (x) \right) $$

Can someone please help me get the answer the professor gave? It's either the professor is wrong or the calculators are.

author's edit: thank you so much to everyone who helped clarify this! it's greatly appreciated :DDD

Comment: Remember that $\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=\cos(2x)$ and that $2\cos(x)\sin(x)=\sin(2x)$. With these you can check that the two are equal.

Comment: Just because the two are expressed differently, it doesn't mean they aren't equivalent.  $\frac12\sin^3(2x)\cos(2x)=4\frac1{2^3}\sin^3(2x)\cos(2x)=4(\sin(x)\cos(x))^3(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x))=4\cos^3(x)\sin^3(x)(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your professor have used the following way:
$$\sin x \cos x =\frac12 \sin 2x$$ $$\cos^4 x \sin^4 x = \frac1{16} \sin^4 2x$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\cos^4 x \sin^4 x)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac1{16} \sin^4 2x\right)=\frac1{16}\cdot 4\sin^3 2x \cdot \cos 2x \cdot 2=\frac1{2} \sin^3 2x \cos 2x$$

Answer (score 0):

It seems just largely the formatting of the final form and simple use of the product rule. Note that if you have some $y = u(x)v(x)$ then $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{du}{dx}*v + u * \frac{dv}{dx}$. With this in mind just treat $u(x) = cos^{4}x$ and $v(x) = sin^{4}x$.

The derivative of $cos^{4}x = 4 * cos^{3}x * -sinx$ and similarly the derivative of $sin^{4}x = 4 * sin^{3}x * cosx$

So our expression $y = cos^{4}x * sin^{4}x$ evaluates to $\frac{dy}{dx} = (4 * cos^{3}x * -sinx) * sin^{4}x + (4 * sin^{3}x * cosx) * cos^{4}x$

So far so good, we can simplify and clean up to:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = (-4sin^{5}xcos^{3}x) + (4sin^{3}xcos^{5}x)$

From here we can factor out the "4"s as well as $sin^{3}xcos^{3}x$ since those appear in both terms of the expression.

$\frac{dy}{dx} = (4sin^{3}cos^{3}x)(-sin^{2}x + cos^{2}x)$

Now this part takes some familiarity with trigonometric identities, but basically using the identity $sin^{2}x + cos^{2}x = 1$ and therefore $-sin^{2}x = cos^{2}x - 1$ we can substitute the right-hand side brackets into:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = (4sin^{3}cos^{3}x)(2cos^{2}x - 1)$

The rest requires knowledge of double angle identities. Note that $sin2x = 2sinxcosx$. Similarly $sin^{3}2x = (2sinxcosx)^{3} = 8sin^{3}xcos^{3}x$. Notice how our left bracket is that expression divided by 2?

That is how we go from $\frac{dy}{dx} = (4sin^{3}cos^{3}x)(2cos^{2}x - 1)$

to $\frac{dy}{dx} = (\frac{1}{2})(8sin^{3}xcos^{3}x)(2cos^{2}x - 1)$

to $\frac{dy}{dx} = (\frac{1}{2})(sin^{3}2x)(2cos^{2}x - 1)$.

Finally, we use the double angle identity of $cos2x = cos^{2}x - sin^{2}x$.

Using our original trig identity manipulation, where $-sin^{2}x = cos^{2}x - 1$, we can substitute $cos2x = 2cos^{2}x - 1$ and coincidentally this equals our right bracket expression. Plugging that in we get:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = (\frac{1}{2})(sin^{3}2x)(cos2x)$

which is the answer your professor gave. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First let us start by differentiating $\cos ^4(x)$ and $\sin ^4(x)$

$\frac{d}{dx} \cos ^4(x) = -4\cos^3(x)\sin(x)$

$\frac{d}{dx} \sin ^4(x) = 4\sin^3(x)\cos(x)$

We get both of these through the chain rule.

Now, recall the product rule which says

$(uv)'= uv' + u'v$

Notice that our question requires $u = \sin^4(x)$ and $v = \cos ^4(x)$(interchangeably, of course).

Hence we use the product rule to get the following

$\frac{d}{dx}\sin^4(x)\cos^4(x) = -4\cos^3(x)\sin^5(x) + 4\sin^3(x)\cos^5(x)$

$\frac{d}{dx}\sin^4(x)\cos^4(x) = 4\cos^3(x)\sin^3(x)(\cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x))$

We know that $\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)$ and $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x) \implies \frac{1}{2}\sin^3(2x) = 4\sin^3(x)\cos^3(x)$

From these identities, we get your professor's solution.